# Refactor Github workflow for Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, github-actions

I have a github workflow file that builds a laravel application and uploads it as a release, but I feel like the command for archiving the files can be done in one line without creating a "dist" folder

I initially create a folder called "dist" and copy all files excluding the "node_modules" and ".git" directory into it.

```
name: "Build and Deploy"

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*.*.*"
permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        with:
          version: 7
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: "pnpm"

      - uses: php-actions/composer@v6
        with:
          dev: no
          php_version: latest
          args: --profile --ignore-platform-reqs

      - name: Copy env
        run: cp .env.example .env

      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Build
        run: pnpm run build

      - name: Create dist
        run: |
          mkdir dist
          find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
          ! -name ".git" \
          ! -name "dist" \
          ! -name "node_modules" \
          -exec cp -R -t dist {} +

      - uses: montudor/action-zip@v1
        with:
          args: zip -qq -r build.zip dist

      - name: Release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
        with:
          files: |
            build.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any dedicated action (like `montudor/action-zip@v1`) for zipping files. If you look at the [tooling installed on the ubuntu-latest](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md) runner you can find `zip` is already there and it's ready to use in your workflow.

First, remove `Create dist` and `montudor/action-zip@v1` steps and replace them with a new `Create dist` step. You can pass multiple `--exclude` flags to filter out undesired files using the native `zip` binary. The flag accepts wildcards:

```
steps:
...
- name: Create build.zip
  run: |
    zip -qq -r build.zip . --exclude '.git\*' --exclude 'node_modules\*'
```

Comment: Thanks. What really worked is `zip -qq -r build.zip . -x ".git/*" -x "node_modules/*"`